# Brunch based build/karma test with `require 'moment'` results in Cannot find module "moment"

Tags: momentjs, brunch

For some reason, I'm not having a problem requiring `jquery`, but I am with `moment`.  The error I receive is:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "moment" from "/"    app.js:62:11
  require   app.js:62:11
```

When I debug my `vendor.js` in the section of code where `moment` is included, I see:

```
 // CommonJS module is defined
    if (hasModule) {
        module.exports = moment;
        makeGlobal(true);
    } else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define("moment", function (require, exports, module) {
            if (module.config && module.config() && module.config().noGlobal !== true) {
                // If user provided noGlobal, he is aware of global
                makeGlobal(module.config().noGlobal === undefined);
            }

            return moment;
        });
    } else {
        makeGlobal();
    }
```

The `hasModule` returns false:

```
// check for nodeJS
        hasModule = (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports && typeof require !== 'undefined'),
```

So it runs the `makeGlobal()` method.  I can't quite get a grasp on why `hasModule` is false.  Perhaps this detection code executes prior to the `brunch` definition code?  Clearly I have `moment` properly configured as a dependency because it is indeed included in my vendor.js file, so why does `moment = require 'moment'` fail with `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "moment" from "/"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brunch doesn't wrap vendor libraries in module definitions. You can move `moment.js` to `app/` directory OR you should just use `moment` global variable.

Expanding on Paul's comment:
What I did was 1) left moment to be compiled into the vendor.js 2) remove the require in the spec

Then the following worked in the spec without anything else required:

```
  mom = moment()
  expect(moment).not.toBeNull()
```

Comment: Where can I read more on require and modules?  I'd like to extend moment in a manner similar to [strftime](https://github.com/benjaminoakes/moment-strftime/blob/master/lib/moment-strftime.coffee) but continue to run into issues due to lack of knowledge on modules/require.  I think if  I get a background on it I should be good.